# Is this good to make many https websocket servers for every page that needs data auto update on my site?

Tags: node.js, express, https, websocket

I have 5 pages with different data which content always dynamically changes. I have site on hosting and VPS  which uses node js, websocket, cors, express, https and force ssl. I'm making for each page individual https and websocket server, it listens different ports for clients connection. When site on hosting sends new data to VPS, it sends this data to array of users for chosen page.
Is this good to make many individual https websocket servers for every page that needs dynamically updating data? For example if I want to make 15 such pages?

```
let storeHouseServer = https.createServer(options,app);
let pointsServer = https.createServer(options,app);
let workUserServer = https.createServer(options,app);
let statementUserServer = https.createServer(options, app);

storeHouseServer.listen(storeHousePort, function() {
    console.log(new Date() + " Server is listening on port " + storeHousePort);
});
pointsServer.listen(pointPort, function() {
    console.log(new Date() + " Server is listening on port " + storeHousePort);
});
workUserServer.listen(workUserPort, function() {
    console.log(new Date() + " Server is listening on port " + workUserPort);
});
statementUserServer.listen(statementUserPort, function() {
    console.log(new Date() + " Server is listening on port " + statementUserPort);
});

let wsStoreHouseServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: storeHouseServer
});
let wsPointsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: pointsServer
});
let workWsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: workUserServer
});
let statementWsServer = new webSocketServer({
    httpServer: statementUserServer
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would typically not make a separate webSocket server for every page that uses a webSocket just like you don't make a different web server for every web page on your site.

Instead, you would make one webSocket server that each page can send its own messages and data to and the one server can discern based on the information it is sent what it is being asked to do and send an appropriate response.

If you use socket.io (a layer on top of webSocket), then you additionally have messages, namespaces and rooms that give you even more flexibility for how to communicate over the one server.